# After refactoring function inside closure is unused

Tags: swift, automated-refactoring

I was extracting closure to method but I always get this error:

*Function is unused*

This is whole working func:

```
        fileprivate func attemptToChangePassword() {
    
    passwordChanger.change(securityToken: securityToken, oldPassword: oldPassword.text ?? "", newPassword: newPassword.text ?? "", onSuccess:{[weak self] in
        self?.hideSpinner()
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: nil,
            message: "Your password has been successfully changed.",
            preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okButton = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default) { [weak self] _ in
                self?.dismiss(animated: true)
            }
        alertController.addAction(okButton)
        alertController.preferredAction = okButton
        self?.present(alertController, animated: true)
        
    }, onFailure: {[weak self] message in
        self?.hideSpinner()
        self?.showAlert(message: message) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.oldPassword.text = ""
            self?.newPassword.text = ""
            self?.confirmPassword.text = ""
            self?.oldPassword.becomeFirstResponder()
            self?.view.backgroundColor = .white
            self?.blurView.removeFromSuperview()
            self?.cancel.isEnabled = true
        }
            
    })
}
```

This is how I extracted last closure to method:

```
fileprivate func startOver() -> (UIAlertAction) -> Void {
    return { [weak self] _ in
        self?.oldPassword.text = ""
        self?.newPassword.text = ""
        self?.confirmPassword.text = ""
        self?.oldPassword.becomeFirstResponder()
        self?.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self?.blurView.removeFromSuperview()
        self?.cancel.isEnabled = true
    }
}
```

If I try this, the error *"Function is unused"* shows up:

```
  onFailure: { [weak self] message in
 self?.hideSpinner()
 self?.showAlert(message: message) { [weak self] _ in
  self?.startOver()//FUNCTION IS UNUSED
  }
 })
```

Edit:

Here is alert method that is used:

```
      fileprivate func showAlert( message: String, okAction: @escaping (UIAlertAction) -> Void) {
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler:okAction)
    ac.addAction(ok)
    ac.preferredAction = ok
    self.present(ac, animated: true)
}
```

If I add back alert action button it works:

```
let okButton = UIAlertAction(
            title: "OK",
            style: .default,
            handler:startOver())
```

Comment: You are calling the `startOver()` function that returns another function of type `(UIAlertAction) -> Void`, but you are not using it. Did you try replacing that line with `let _ = self?.startOver()`?

Comment: Try `self?.startOver()()`

Comment: Yes I've tried both _ = self?.startOver and let  _ = self?.startOver(If there are any differences) But my tests still fail. @HunterLion

Comment: @aheze I just got new error about inserting alertAction If I do that. "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently calling that function inside of the action you pass to your `showAlert` function but then throwing away the action it returns. Instead, you want to pass the action that it returns directly to your `showAlert` method rather than wrapping it inside another action with the trailing closure syntax:

```
self?.showAlert(message: message, okAction: self!.startOver())
```